# Python3.8で`list`を使って型エイリアスを定義する方法

Tags: python, python3

## 環境

- Python3.8.6

## 背景

Python3.8以上で動作するコードを書いています。

型ヒントを付ける際、今までは`typing.List`などを使っていました。
しかしPython3.9では`typing.List`などが非推奨になったので、`from __future__ import annotations`を実行して`list`を利用できるようにしました。

## 問題

以下のサイトにあるように、`list`を使って型エイリアスを定義したいです。
https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/typing.html#type-aliases

```
from __future__ import annotations

Vector = list[float]

def scale(scalar: float, vector: Vector) -> Vector:
    return [scalar * num for num in vector]

# typechecks; a list of floats qualifies as a Vector.
new_vector = scale(2.0, [1.0, -4.2, 5.4])
```

しかし、以下のエラーが発生しました。

```
$ python foo.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "foo.py", line 5, in <module>
    Vector = list[float]
TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable
```

## 質問

Python3.8で`list`を使って型エイリアスを定義するのには、どのように書けばよいでしょうか？

以下のように`typing.List`を使用すれば動きますが、Python3.9では非推奨なので、できればこのような書き方はしたくありません。

```
from typing import List
Vector = List[float]
```

Comment: yuji38kwmt さん、 https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/84109/19110 にて疑問が解決したとマークなさっていますが、この情報は質問文や既存の回答でも示されていた情報なのではないかと思います。念の為、正しい操作かどうかご確認いただけないでしょうか。

Comment: すみません、解決済にする回答を間違えていました。訂正します。

Comment: ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 2, accepted):

型ヒントとして使う場合は, 次のように指定可能だけど

```py
>>> from __future__ import annotations
>>> vct: list[float]
```

代入で使う (`Vector = list[float]`) 場合は Python 3.9 以降の機能の様なので
どうしても使いたい場合は, こんな風にするとか？

```py
if sys.version_info[0:2] == (3,8):
    from typing import List as list

Vector = list[float]
# 他のなにか

if sys.version_info[0:2] == (3,8):
    del list # これ以降は普通の list
```

Comment: 代入で使う場合はPython3.9以降の機能なんですね。それを知らずに質問してしまいました。そうなると諦めた方がよさそう。

Comment: すみません「の様に」(思える)というだけです。 "こんな風に指定" できるようにしていく, という以前の記事見かけたので。PEPのウォッチしている方がいれば何か判るかも